# rvm doesn't install in centos without root privileges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I trying to install RVM using deployer user that doesn't had root privileges ant I getting
this error:

```
bash: line 439: ./scripts/install: Permission denied
```

Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: what is the command you run to install rvm?

Comment: @mpapis, `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Comment: and this was the only message you see? you can update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to install rvm in folder mounted with noexec option.

Mounting partition without this option works!