# Error creating setting up rails environment on CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I trying to deploy rails app in CentOS 6.3 for 3 days, and I had no success until now.
I want to use rbenv, but I am getting these errors:

I created a new user 'deployer' and installed rbenv using it. Logout and Login again.
When I log in, I get this error:

```
-bash: /home/deployer/.rbenv/bin/rbenv: Permission denied
```

If I install rbenv using root user, It loads rbenv after install, but the error is when I try install ruby:

```
$ rbenv install 1.9.3-p125
Downloading yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/36c852831d02cf90508c29852361d01b
Installing yaml-0.1.4...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20121214131627.11110
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20121214131627.11110.log

Last 10 log lines:
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/run_parser.vcproj
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/yaml.vcproj
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/test_version.vcproj
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/run_emitter.vcproj
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/example_reformatter.vcproj
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/run_loader.vcproj
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/yamldll.vcproj
yaml-0.1.4/win32/config.h
/tmp/ruby-build.20121214131627.11110/yaml-0.1.4 /tmp/ruby-build.20121214131627.11110 ~
/root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin/ruby-build: line 321: ./configure: Permission denied
```

**EDIT**

Permissions of rbenv installed by deployer:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  8 deployer  deployer  4096 Dec 14 13:11 .rbenv
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was getting this error because folder was mounted with `noexec` option.

Same solution of this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13973592/740394

Answer (score 0):

First, check the prmissions and owner for /home/deployer/.rbenv

In second example, i think, you are running install under user. Try run it under root.

Comment: In first, prmissions and owner for /home/deployer/.rbenv are ok. In second, I running install under root.

Comment: can are you run "ls -la /home/deployer/.rbenv/bin/" and get output

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ~/.rbenv was created by another user

try

```
$ sudo chown -R deployer ~deployer/.rbenv
```

Answer (score 0):

Am getting the same error. I think yaml is the culprit here. if we can install ruby without yaml then install yaml later